# Why do we produce black plastic items if they cannot be recycled?

Tags: recycling

My local council accepts white plastic for recycling. If white is ok, why do we produce meat packaging, frozen meal packaging etc in black?

Comment: Your information is out-of-date, nowadays it can. But maybe not all installations yet.

Comment: @JanDoggen that answer doesn't answer the main question here - since black plastic is harder to recycle, why is it used? I assume there's some functional or financial reason, which isn't discussed at that question. Perhaps a better way to phrase this question would be, "Are there cheaper or better alternatives to black plastic which are easier to recycle?"

Comment: If I can find a reference I'll post an answer, but I seem to remember (from our council's recycling update a while back) that black is what they do with recycled plastic that's got too much residual colour to do anything else

Answer (score 7):

One reason for using black plastic for meat packaging is the hide the blood that can sometimes seep out of the meat. It gives the appearance of a cleaner presentation. I've seen meat packaged in white & black plastic trays and the black ones always look neater & give the appearance of being cleaner.

The choice of a color for a plastic item, such as packaging, may be more of a marketing decision than an environmental one. Not everyone is concerned with sustainability & the environment, some people are more concerned about making money & improving only their quality of life irrespective of the impact that may have on others or the environment.

Comment: Strangely enough, around here meat is rarely seen in anything other than clear/white trays (UK supermarkets) so this isn't a universal preference.

Comment: Packaged meat often has an absorbing pad below it.

Comment: U.K. Supermarkets I have seen all have red meat in black trays and poultry in white trays. Red meat also has an absorbent pad.

Comment: @Rory Funnily enough I found an exception - chicken breasts from sainsbury's are in a black tray. We don't eat very much red meat but most of what we do comes in a clear/white tray (sainsbury's again)